# Nesting a table with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a table, and I want to display a tr beneath a tr when it is clicked. 
It works fine, but I want to have the second tr be nested within a table. When I put it within a table, however, it fails to display.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.viewCustomerDetails">
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: first_name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: last_name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="attr: {id: $data.id}, style: {color: 'red', display: 'none'}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.address"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.last_logon"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.telephone"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.fraud"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the Js:

```
self.viewCustomerDetails = function(i, e){
                var row = $('#' + i.id());
                $('#' + i.id()).toggle();
            }
        };
```

Comment: As shown, the HTML isn't quite valid.  Can you post a mcve with correct markup and a complete view model?  This will make it easier for us to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You seem to be mixing jQuery with knockout as well.  Rather than doing something like `$('#' + i.id()).toggle();`, the more idiomatic approach in knockout would be to set a boolean `observable` on each of your `customers`.  The 2nd `tr` would then just use the `visible` binding, rather than using `display: none` and relying on jQuery to show it.

Comment: Try nesting the table inside a <td>. Yu are nesting it directly inside the <tr>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this. You can do the following:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.viewCustomerDetails">
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: first_name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: last_name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="visible: showDetails">
       <td colspan="4">
           <table>
                <tr>
                   <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: last_logon"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: telephone"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: fraud"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
function Customer () {
   var self = this;
   //your properties id, first_name, last_name
   self.showDetails = ko.observable(false);
}

function CustomersViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   //your observableArrays, that contains a collection of Customer, declared above
   self.viewCustomerDetails = function (customer) {
       customer.showDetails(!customer.showDetails());
   }
}

ko.applyBindings(new CustomersViewModel());
```